# Exception thrown while trying to send mail through gmail SMTP

Tags: c#, .net, system.net.mail, system.net

The below exception is thrown while trying to send mail by below code:

```
SMPT server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was 5.5.1. Authentication required
```

C#

```
string E_mail_ID = "hidden";
        try
        {
            SmtpClient gmail_client = new SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com");
            gmail_client.Port = 587;

            gmail_client.EnableSsl = true;
            gmail_client.Timeout = 100000;
            gmail_client.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;
            gmail_client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;
            gmail_client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("hidden", "hidden");

            MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
            msg.From = new MailAddress("hidden");
            msg.To.Add(E_mail_ID.Trim());              
            msg.Body = "Request for quotation from Jeet fly ash products, a unit of Vidya shakti niyas";
            msg.Attachments.Add(new Att![enter image description here][1]achment(pdfFile));
            gmail_client.Send(msg);
            MessageBox.Show("RFQ sent to vendor successfully");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Where is the exception?

Comment: And what is the exception?

Comment: " SMPT server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was 5.5.1. Authentication required ". This is the exception which is shown by the message box when I send to a mail address

Answer (score 0):

Try the port: 465 - This is ssl for gmail.

Take a look: [Configure Gmail-Account Outlook](https://support.google.com/mail/troubleshooter/1668960?hl=en&from=75726&rd=1#ts=1665119,1665157,2769079)

Comment: Same exception is coming.

Comment: Hmmm.. are you using Google-Authenticator? & Is POP-Enabled for your account?

Comment: @Jagmeet:taka look at this thread- using System.Net.Mail instead of System.Web.Mail (because web.mail has issues with ssl)

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32260/sending-email-in-net-through-gmail